# enzyme - how can I check if the component is unmounted?

Tags: javascript, tdd, enzyme

As the title is, How can I check if a component is unmounted?

I tried to check it using `component.length`, but it always has length(not zero).

Is there a way to check if a component unmounted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An unmounted component should be no more part of the DOM representation.

Therefore you should be able to use enzyme's [`exists`](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ReactWrapper/exists.md) method on your unmounted component selector:

```
const component = wrapper.find('MyUnmountedComponent');
expect(component.exists()).toBe(false);
```